# Get Files matching a date criteria

Tags: command-line

I have done a small *.bat file which the following command exists:

`forfiles /p %sourcedir% /m *.* /c "cmd /c echo @path && if /l @fdate == %date% (echo true) else (echo false)"`

The above checks whether file's modified date is today or not.

I am getting the error after I run it

> 09/02/2017 was unexpected at this time. 
>   29/01/2018 was unexpected at this time. 
>   13/08/2018 was unexpected at this time.

Note, in the %sourcedir% I have one file that matches the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Forfiles default /M searchmask is *, so it can be omitted.

Forfiles also had a /D date argument, where date can be a date or a the current date plus 'dd' days.  Using /D 0 would be today.

This reduces the batch file command to:

forfiles /p %sourcedir% /d 0 /c "cmd /c echo @path"

Note: only files that match the condition will be echoed.

Comment: It would be helpful to add further detail to this answer, explain what the commands you are suggesting do, and how they solve the problem at hand.